# how to fetch json in retrofit2

Tags: android, json

I am making and android app in which i am fetching json data from api but i dont know how to fetch json data,the getter and setter class where we pass serialize.
Here is my json data `{"status":true,"message":"Notifications fetched.","data":[{"id":"69","type":"liked","text":"Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.","for_userid":"56","from_userid":"55","for_image":"54","seen":"0","username":"sandip","firstname":"Sandip","lastname":"Ghosh","imgname":""},{"id":"64","type":"liked","text":"Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.","for_userid":"56","from_userid":"55","for_image":"54","seen":"0","username":"sandip","firstname":"Sandip","lastname":"Ghosh","imgname":""},{"id":"63","type":"liked","text":"Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.","for_userid":"56","from_userid":"55","for_image":"54","seen":"0","username":"sandip","firstname":"Sandip","lastname":"Ghosh","imgname":""},{"id":"62","type":"commented","text":"Sandip Ghosh commented onyour photo.","for_userid":"56","from_userid":"55","for_image":"54","seen":"0","username":"sandip","firstname":"Sandip","lastname":"Ghosh","imgname":""},{"id":"61","type":"liked","text":"Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.","for_userid":"56","from_userid":"55","for_image":"53","seen":"0","username":"sandip","firstname":"Sandip","lastname":"Ghosh","imgname":""},{"id":"27","type":"Follow","text":"Sandip Ghosh started following you","for_userid":"56","from_userid":"55","for_image":"0","seen":"1","username":"sandip","firstname":"Sandip","lastname":"Ghosh","imgname":""}]}`

Comment: care to post your code??

Answer (score 0):

Put your whole json to http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ 
this will create models itself for you.
It will create Serializable models with no effort.
Then use those models to get values.
For more follow below tutorial : 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit